# My rails server constantly freezing after any saved change in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

Example:

I'm changing something in controller, save it, and then refresh the page. Page is loading, and loading, and loading (same for server logs)... I can't kill server (CTRL + C doesn't work). I have to close tab, delete server pid and start server again.

```
Puma version: 6.0.0 (ruby 3.0.4-p208) ("Sunflower")
Ruby version: 3.0.4
Rails version: 6.1.6
```

EDIT 1:

```
MemTotal:       16351512 kB
MemFree:         6512996 kB
MemAvailable:   10926512 kB
```

This is what I got after visit `localhost:3000/rails/locks`

```
Thread 0 [0xe54c sleep]  No lock (yielded share)
  Waiting in start_exclusive to "unload"
  may be pre-empted for: "load", "unload"
  blocked by: 1

/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/monitor.rb:108:in `sleep'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/monitor.rb:108:in `wait'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/monitor.rb:108:in `wait_for_cond'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/monitor.rb:108:in `wait'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/monitor.rb:116:in `wait_while'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:220:in `wait_for'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:83:in `block (2 levels) in start_exclusive'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:187:in `yield_shares'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:82:in `block in start_exclusive'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/monitor.rb:202:in `synchronize'
/usr/share/rvm/rubies/ruby-3.0.4/lib/ruby/3.0.0/monitor.rb:202:in `mon_synchronize'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/concurrency/share_lock.rb:77:in `start_exclusive'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies/interlock.rb:25:in `start_unloading'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:100:in `require_unload_lock!'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:119:in `class_unload!'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/railties-6.1.6/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:244:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Finisher>'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `instance_exec'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:427:in `block in make_lambda'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:198:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:604:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:603:in `catch'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:603:in `block in default_terminator'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:199:in `block in halting'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:512:in `block in invoke_before'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:512:in `each'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:512:in `invoke_before'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:105:in `run_callbacks'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:114:in `run!'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:114:in `run!'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:77:in `block in run!'
<internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:74:in `run!'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:63:in `run!'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:18:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/better_errors-2.9.1/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:87:in `protected_app_call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/better_errors-2.9.1/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:82:in `better_errors_call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/better_errors-2.9.1/lib/better_errors/middleware.rb:60:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:29:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/web-console-4.2.0/lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/railties-6.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:37:in `call_app'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/railties-6.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `block in call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/activesupport-6.1.6/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/railties-6.1.6/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/sprockets-rails-3.4.2/lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:81:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/request_store-1.5.1/lib/request_store/middleware.rb:19:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:24:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/rack-2.2.4/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_locks.rb:41:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/actionpack-6.1.6/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:148:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/rack-mini-profiler-2.3.4/lib/mini_profiler/profiler.rb:393:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/webpacker-5.4.3/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:25:in `perform_request'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/rack-proxy-0.7.2/lib/rack/proxy.rb:67:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/railties-6.1.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:539:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:268:in `call'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/request.rb:89:in `block in handle_request'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:343:in `with_force_shutdown'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/request.rb:88:in `handle_request'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/server.rb:430:in `process_client'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/server.rb:233:in `block in run'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:150:in `block in spawn_thread'


---


Thread 1 [0xe150 sleep]  Sharing
  blocking: 0

/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:136:in `sleep'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:136:in `wait'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:136:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_thread'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `synchronize'
/home/maciej/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.0.4/gems/puma-6.0.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

My console logs are normal. I mean... They appear very slowly, but they are correct

Comment: are you low on RAM? it takes some time/CPU power for garbage collector to free it up

Comment: What is the log output after the code change when refreshing the page?

Comment: You might try Rails' [DebugLocks](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/DebugLocks.html) middleware to debug autoload related deadlocks. (visit http://localhost:3000/rails/locks after enabling it)

Comment: @Stefan  I edited question and provide more info

Comment: A) Does this happen on a new project, or other Rails projects on your machine? B) Do you monitor CPU and memory usage with something like `htop`?

Comment: @tadman A) I don't have other apps right now. It all starts when I updated some gems (including Puma). B) No

Comment: It could be some kind of incompatibility, but it's really hard to say. The most common cause of a "slow" server is some other component, like a database being flaky/down, though if Puma is broken that'd explain a lot. You could try with an alternative there, or roll back Puma to a known-good version.

Comment: @tadman I roll back Puma, and now it works. I suppose I will leave it as it is.

Comment: While Puma has generally been pretty good about releases, seeing `.0.0` at the end has me worried something broke.